# r - Rd2pdf error about TeX binary

Tags: r, package, latex, reference-manual

I created an R package in RStudio using devtools and roxygen2. I have the project file open and I now want to take all of the documentation for my functions and put it together into a pdf reference manual. I ran

```
system("R CMD Rd2pdf .")
```

which gave me the following error:

```
# Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
#  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rd2.tex' failed.

# Output:
# You don't have a working TeX binary (tex) installed anywhere in
# your PATH, and texi2dvi cannot proceed without one.  If you want to use
# this script, you'll need to install TeX (if you don't have it) or change
# your PATH or TEX environment variable (if you do).  See the --help
# output for more details.

# For information about obtaining TeX, please see http://www.tug.org.  If
# you happen to be using Debian, you can get it with this command:
#  apt-get install tetex-bin
# Error in running tools::texi2pdf()
```

I'm using OS X 10.10 and I have MacTeX installed (it's sitting in my Applications folder). I'm a beginner at R and LaTeX so I'm not sure what the error message means when it says that I don't have a **working TeX binary** installed. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging around, I found out that the error I was getting has to do with the
Yosemite upgrade.

The workaround is to launch RStudio from terminal as suggested on [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-rstudio-incompatibility-with-yosemite-mac-os-x-10-10/).

When I did this, I was able to produce the reference manual just fine.